# Why Flask Server needs to restart after running a motor?

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am very new to raspberry pi and Python. I want to develop a Flask and Python web server for my raspberry pi small project. I have developed Flask and Python server to drive ESC (Electronic Speed Control) brushless motors but i have an issue regarding flask.

**For GPIO Controlling, I used Rpi.GPIO library.**

The issue is,
when I click on the **motor/on** link it runs the motor and when click on **motor/off** link, the motor turned off. Now if I again click on the **motor/on** link it isn't running the motor until unless I restart my Flask app. After restarting Flask app **(app.py)** file then the **motor/on** link works properly i don't know why it happens. I hope i am clear.

Here is my Flask app.py code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
import time

motor = 12

GPIO.setup(motor, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(motor, 50)


@app.route("/<deviceName>/<action>")

def action(deviceName, action):
    
    if deviceName == 'motor':
        actuator = motor
        
    if action == "on":
        p.start(9)
        
    if action == "off":
        p.stop()
        

    return make_response(action)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: `.start()` and `.stop()` are methods intended to be used at most once each over the lifetime of a PWM object.  `.ChangeDutyCycle()` is the method you're supposed to use to make ongoing changes to the output power level.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
I added p.ChangeDutyCycle(7.5) below p.start() and p.ChangeDutyCycle(0) to below p.stop() but it didn't solved the issue.
Could you please answer me with a proper edited code. It will be really helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: `p.start()` should be just after the definition of `p`, `p.stop()` should be removed completely.

Comment: I done the same as you described. But it doesn't work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
import time

motor = 12

GPIO.setup(motor, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(motor, 50)
p.start(0)       # EDIT


@app.route("/<deviceName>/<action>")

def action(deviceName, action):
    
    if deviceName == 'motor':
        actuator = motor
        
    if action == "on":
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(9)    # EDIT
        
    if action == "off":
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)    # EDIT
        

    return make_response(action)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

And maybe place the p.stop() anywhere at the end of your programm.